# Characterization of Brownian motion: processes with right-continuous paths

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales

I am looking for a reference with a proof for the following fact:

If a right-continuous martingale $(X_r)_{ r \geq 0}$ is such that $X_0=0,(X^2_r-r)_r,(X_r^3-3rX_r)_r,(X_r^4-6rX_r^2+3r^2)_r$ are martingales then $(X_r)_{r}$ is a Brownian motion.

Comment: It is not ideal to cross list the same question here and on Math Stack exchange at the same time. Better to post it on one site, and if there is no answer after 5 days, say, then it is fine to post on the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to prove that the paths are continuous, and then the result follows from
https://almostsuremath.com/2010/04/13/levys-characterization-of-brownian-motion/

A version of this question was also asked on math stack exchange, for convenience I include the proof also here.

**Proposition**
Let $(X_u)_{u}$ be right-continuous martingale with $X_0=0$, such that $(X^2_u-u)_u,(X_u^3-3uX_u)_u,(X_u^4-6uX_u^2+3u^2)_u$ are martingales. Then for every integer $M \ge 1$, the path $(X_u)_{u}$ is a.s. continuous in $[0,M]$.

**Proof:** Let $\{\mathcal F_t\}$ be the canonical filtration of  $\{X_t\}$. Fix $u \ge 0$ and write
$E^u[\,\cdot\,]:=E[\,\cdot \,| \mathcal F_u]$. Denote $\mathcal G_t:=\mathcal F_{u+t}$  for $t \ge 0$. Observe that the process $\{Y_t\}_{t \ge 0}$ defined by $$Y_t:=X_{u+t}-X_u \tag{1}$$ is a
$\{\mathcal G_t\}$-martingale.

**Claim:** For any bounded $\{\mathcal G_t\}$-stopping time $\tau$, we have
$$E^u[Y_\tau^4]=3E^u[\tau^2]\,.$$

The claim is proved below. Now we will use it to complete the proof of the proposition.

Fix $\epsilon>0$  and $\delta>0$. Let $P^u[\,\cdot\,]:=P[\,\cdot \, | \mathcal F_u]$. Applying the claim to
$$\tau:=\delta \wedge \min\{t\ge 0: |Y_t| \ge \epsilon\}$$
gives
$$P^u[|Y_\tau| \ge \epsilon]\cdot\epsilon^4 \le E^u[Y_\tau^4] \le 3\delta^2\,,$$
so
$$P[|Y_\tau| \ge \epsilon] \le 3\delta^2 \epsilon^{-4}\,. \tag{*}$$
For $k \ge 1$, we will use $(*)$ for $\delta_k={32}^{-k}$ and $\epsilon_k=2^{-k}$ to bound the probability of
$$A_k:=\bigcup_{j=0}^{{32}^k M-1} \Big\{\max_{0 \le t \le \delta_k} |X_{j\delta_k+t}-X_{j\delta_k}| \ge \epsilon_k\Big\} \,.$$
We obtain
$$P(A_k) \le 32^k M \cdot 3\delta_k^2 \epsilon_k^{-4}=3M\epsilon_k\,.$$
By  the Borel-Cantelli lemma, almost surely only finitely many of the events $A_k$ occur. This implies that $\{X_t\}$ is a.s. continuous in $[0,M]$.
$\hspace{6.6in} \Box$

**Proof of Claim**

$$X_u-u^2= E^u[(X_u+Y_\tau)^2-(u+\tau)]\,, \quad \text{so} \quad E^u[Y_\tau^2-\tau]=0 \,. \tag{2}$$
Similarly,
$$X_u^3-3uX_u=E^u[(X_u+Y_\tau)^3-3(u+\tau)(X_u+Y_\tau)]\,, \quad \text{so by} \; (2),$$
$$E^u[Y_\tau^3-3\tau Y_\tau]=0 \,. \tag{3}$$
Also,
$$X_u^4-6uX_u^2+3u^2=E^u[(X_u+Y_\tau)^4-6(u+\tau)(X_u+Y_\tau)^2+3(u+\tau)^2]\,, $$
so
$$0=E^u[Y_\tau^4+4X_u Y_\tau^3+6X_u^2 Y_\tau^2-6u Y_\tau^2-12\tau X_u Y_\tau-6\tau(X_u^2+Y_\tau^2)+6u\tau+3\tau^2]  \,.  $$
Therefore,
$$E^u[Y_\tau^4]=4X_u E^u[Y_\tau^3-3\tau Y_\tau]+6(X_u^2-u) E^u[Y_\tau^2-\tau] +3E^u[\tau^2]=3E^u[\tau^2]\,. \tag{4}$$
$\hspace{6.6in} \Box$